# How to ignore word in a certain position in lines being read?

Tags: c++, c++11

My code first opens the file and gets each line from it, each line taking the form:

`HEX_NUM CHAR HEX_NUM`

The code I have is

```
stringstream s( line );
s >> std::hex >> addr >> letter >> std::hex >> target ;
```

However, I would like to only get the CHAR section (without having the create the variables `addr` and `target`). How can I rewrite the 2nd line of my code to do so?

Comment: Use `s.ignore(..., ' ')` instead of `s >> ...` for the `addr` value, and don't even read the `target` value. Alternatively, don't use `stringstream` at all, just parse the `line` directly, using `string::find_first(_not)_of()` to find the start and end indexes of the `CHAR` value, and then `string::substr()` or `string::operator[]` to extract it

Answer (score 0):

If the input line strictly followed your pattern(only two spaces in the line, and there are words between the two spaces), then we can simply use `std::string::find` and `std::string::rfind` to exact the middle part.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string str;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
    auto l = str.find(' ');
    auto r = str.rfind(' ');
    if (l < r) {
      std::cout << str.substr(l + 1, r - l) << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

But in reality, we have to deal with a more complex format, then we can choose

- Write regex string to extract the wantted part
- Manually write parsers, which is somewhat time-consuming
- Use simple library `boost::spirit`
- Use some framework like `ANTLR`